# Is it okay to nest divs inside a table cell?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I can't remember the recommendation on this -- should it be avoided? Is it standards complaint?

I have a table -- with actual tabular data inside of it -- but one of the cells contains a bit more information.

The previous developer embedded a child table inside the cell. I'm contemplating replacing it with a pair of floated divs?

Is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't remember the recommendation on this -- should it be avoided?

It smells of divitus, but depends on the specifics.

> Is it standards complaint?

Table cells may contain divs, and divs may contain divs.

> I have a table -- with actual tabular data inside of it -- but one of the cells contains a bit more information.

Perhaps a better structure would involve splitting it into more columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not best choice if the child cell can be converted into normal div block element. **TABLE IN TABLE** is not recommended (*until you have no more choice*)

subtable can be converted into **styled list** to achieve 1xN or Nx1 type tabluar structure

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the previous developer was using HTML tables for layout, which is [generally a bad idea](http://phrogz.net/CSS/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html). It sounds like you're trying to fix the inner cell via a syntactically-correct but semantically-better-but-vapid change. If the outer table is also used for layout (as opposed to being [used for tabular data](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#tables)) then you should fix that as well.

Regarding the "is it legal" part of your question, in the future you may find it easier to try it and then [validate your page](http://validator.w3.org/) instead of waiting for the stack overflow community to roughly validate code concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's fine.

Tables nested inside tables is not recommended (I don't think it's standard compliant either)

The recommended layout is as you suggested - 2 floating DIVs